# Show that X$^3$+X+1|X$^7$+1

Tags: polynomials

This is a part of the question. Which states Let K= $\mathbb{Z}$/2$\mathbb{Z}$[X]/(d)$\mathbb{Z}$/2$\mathbb{Z}$[X], where
 d=X$^3$+X+1 and let a be the class of X modulo d. This is the only part that i do not know how to solve. I have tried calculating the quotient and the remainder but i do not know if it has any meaningful use. And since it has a remainder i cannot find a q(x) that satisfies f(x)=g(x)*q(x). Any tips?

Comment: For the sake of clarity, is $K=\Bbb F_2[X]/(X^3+X+1)$, where $\Bbb F_q$ stands for the field of $q$ elements, an accurate description of your $K$?

Comment: What does $\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z[X]$ denote?

Comment: To be precise, that's quite notation-cluttered, and there should be more parenthesis to disambiguate several non-associative occurrences of "$/$". Also, you are presumably missing a $2$.

Comment: yes you're right it's missing a 2 $\mathbb{Z}$/2$\mathbb{Z}$[X]/(d)$\mathbb{Z}$/2$\mathbb{Z}$[X] is the correct formulation.

Comment: **Hint** $ $ Use *repeated squaring* to compute $\,\large x^7\bmod x^3\!+\!x\!+\!1.\ $ See my answer for the trivial one-line computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps for polynomial long division $\mod 2$, where the notation

$\dfrac{p(X)}{q(X)} \longrightarrow X^k \tag 0$

indicates the quotient of the leading terms is $X^k$:

$\dfrac{X^7 + 1}{X^3 + X + 1} \longrightarrow X^4; \tag 1$

$X^7 + 1 - X^4(X^3 + X + 1) = X^7 + 1 - X^7 - X^5 - X^4 = X^5 + X^4 + 1; \tag 2$

$\dfrac{X^5 + X^4 + 1}{X^3 + X + 1} \longrightarrow X^2; \tag 3$

$X^5 + X^4 + 1 - X^2(X^3 + X + 1) = X^5 + X^4 + 1 - X^5 - X^3 - X^2 = X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + 1; \tag 4$

$\dfrac{X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + 1}{X^3 + X + 1} \longrightarrow X; \tag 5$

$X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + 1 - X(X^3 + X + 1) = X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + 1 - X^4 - X^2 - X = X^3 + X + 1; \tag 6$

$\dfrac{X^3 + X + 1}{X^3 + X + 1} \longrightarrow 1, \tag 7$

and there is clearly no remainder; we gather the terms of the quotient:

$\dfrac{X^7 + 1}{X^3 + X + 1} = X^4 + X^2 + X + 1, \tag 8$

which is easily checked:

$(X^3 + X + 1)( X^4 + X^2 + X + 1)$
$= X^7 + X^5 + X^4 + X^3 + X^5 + X^3 + X^2 + X + X^4 + X^2 + X + 1$
$X^7 + (X^5 + X^5) + (X^4 + X^4) + (X^3 + X^3) +(X^2 + X^2) + (X + X) + 1$
$=  X^7 + 1; \tag 9$

thus we see that

$X^3 + X + 1 \mid X^7 + 1. \tag{10}$

Comment: No need to compute the quotient, e.g. see my one-line  answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\bmod 2,\,\color{#c00}{x^{\large 3}\!+\!x\!+1}\!:\,\ x^{\large 7}\!\equiv x(\color{#c00}{x^{\large 3}})^{\large 2}\equiv x(\color{#c00}{x\!+\!1})^{\large 2}\equiv x^{\large 3}\!+x\equiv -1\ \ $  **QED**

Comment: We used $\ \large {-}1\equiv 1\ $ (by $\,\large 2\equiv 0)\,$ several times above.

Comment: Quite clever${}$!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean  $\;K=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[X]/d(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[X]$.

**Hint**:

If you have to show that $X^3+X+1\mid X^7+1$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[X]$, just perform the Euclidean division of the latter by the former in this polynomial ring. Don't forget that, since  we're in characteristic $2$, subtracting is the same as adding. You should find a quotient of $X^4+X^2+X+1$ if I'm not mistaken.